# Problem not recognizing $router variable in lumen

Tags: php, lumen, modular, lumenworks

I am creating modules in a **modular** way.

But there is a problem in defining the new route, and that is that the **$router** variable does not recognize in the new route.

But if used this way, the problem will be solved: `$this->app->router->get()`

But I want to use the **$router** variable like the `web.php` route default. Can anyone help?

**UserServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../Routes/user_route.php');
    }
}
```

**user_route.php**

```
/** @var Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

//it not work
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

// it works
$this->app->router->get('module/test', function () {
  return 'yohooooo';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the **$route** variable in your own page. If you are trying to shorten the code, you can try a use as follows.

```
$route = $this-app->router;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But why use the same method in a ‍‍web.php‍ ‍‍‍file?